# Is there a way to define a TextBox for Passwords with ipywidgets?

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I am using `ipywidgets` to create text boxes as described in the [documentation](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#Text). That works fine, but I want to create text boxes which show just dots/stars/whatever when an user gives some input, like for a password input box.

Is that possible to do with `ipywidgets`, and if so, how? The documentation is a bit scarce I would say...

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be missing in the documentation, [but it does exist](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/d9e3f239c4e1b3e86802b6a90d4ba7b92acde7a2/ipywidgets/widgets/widget_string.py#L111), we'll need to fix that.

```
import ipywidgets
password_widget = ipywidgets.Password(description='Password:', placeholder='Make it long!')
password_widget
```

In another cell, you can print out it's value:

```
password_widget.value
```

Comment: Just as an FYI - the passwords in the most recent version of ipywidgets are off - the Input style attributes in the default CSS only apply to Inputs with a type of 'text'. If the Input has a type of 'password' instead, and is right next to another Input of the ordinary ipywidgets.Text() class (for something that should be displayed, such as a username) then the two will look different compared to each other.